# In LaTeX beamer, show subitems one by one

Tags: beamer, itemize, subitem

I am attempting this:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Hello
    \item<2-> World
    \begin{itemize}[<.(1)->]
        \item A
        \item B
        \item C
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Unfortunately, it gives me

```
Hello
World
    A
    B
    C
```

all at once. I need the `A`, `B` and `C` to be introduced **one by one**.

Comment: Please don't post just code fragments. Always make a small, but compileable test document including a document class etc.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Will do but tomorrow. Now tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uncover the subitems one by one, you can use `<+->`. If you would like your first subitem to appear on the same slide as `World`, you can modify this to `<+(-1)->`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<+-> Hello
    \item<+-> World
    \begin{itemize}[<+(-1)->]
        \item A
        \item B
        \item C
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want to show subitem A after World is shown?

Comment: @coderodde Use `<+->`